# How to pass Github Auth token in Node Fetch?

Tags: javascript, github-api, node-fetch

I'm currently dealing with API rate:

```
API rate limit exceeded. 
(But here's the good news: 
Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)
```

I've tried multiple different methods, but seems like I'm missing something, here is my current state:

```
const TOKEN = process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN;

  try {
    return await fetch(
      url +
        new URLSearchParams({
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
          },
        })
    ).then((res) => res.json());
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error at Get Pulls", err);
  }
```

I've tried with `Bearer`, without, with lowercase, but at the end I always get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the *headers* and *method* inside the `URLSearchParams`, which is wrong. You must pass these properties to the `fetch` method.

[`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) is a helper to work with the query string of a URL.

So do this instead

```js
await fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
    },
}).then((res) => res.json());
```

Comment: paste your updated code